# Dumping only rooted managed objects and/or statistics on them inside WinDbg

Tags: debugging, windbg, sos, sosex

My problem is that `dumpheap -stat` returns an awful lot of objects and I have no idea which ones are rooted and which ones are not.

Well, I can if I run the `!mroot` or `!refs` command on an individual address, but this approach does not scale very well to thousands of objects reported by `dumpheap`.

For example, `dumpheap -stat` contains the following line:

```
000007fef3d14088    74247      2375904 Microsoft.Internal.ReadLock
```

Wow, 74,247 instances. However, running

```
.logopen c:\tmp\2\log.txt;.foreach (entry {!dumpheap -type Microsoft.Internal.ReadLock -short}){!refs ${entry} -target};.logclose
```

reveals that each and every instance reported by `DumpHeap` is actually unreclaimed garbage!

How I found that each and every instance is garbage is another problem. I had to extract all the `NONE` strings to one file and all the `Objects referencing` strings to another and then compared the number of lines in every file. Surely there is a better way :-(.

Anyway, I would like to know how to focus on the rooted objects only. Ideally, I would like to get the statistics as well as details on such objects.

Comment: My suggestion is to write Steve Johnson (author of SOSEX) an email asking for -short options on !refs and !mroot similar to !dumpheap -short, so that it can be used in further processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop over all objects is already great, just the !refs command needs to be replaced by something else which finds only rooted objects. My example uses Strings, because I don't have an application available using ReadLocks.

There are two possible outputs of the !refs command. A referenced object outputs e.g.

```
Objects referencing 02703f18 (System.String):
follow 02703a88       128   System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo
```

A garbage objects looks like this:

```
Objects referencing 02703f30 (System.String):
NONE
```

You're only interested in the address of the first line in case the second line contains the word "follows". Luckily, the address is equal to `${entry}`, so we actually don't need it. Otherwise you would be in the [same trouble like I am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515857/windbg-using-several-tokens-from-foreach-for-input-of-a-command).

This brings me to [this question about .if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069961/windbg-using-commands-for-the-condition-in-if).

You can use .foreach again on the output of !refs. Let's have a look at this on a single object first:

```
.foreach (reftoken {!refs 027045cc -target}) { .printf "${reftoken}\n" }
```

This prints one word per line and we are interested only in the fifth, which means we can initially skip 4 items and then skip the rest, which gives us

```
.foreach /pS 4 /ps 3 (reftoken {!refs 027045cc -target}) { .printf "${reftoken}\n" }
```

For robustness purposes, let's use `/ps 99`.
Next we need to check if this token equals *follow*, which is done by

```
.if ($sicmp("${reftoken}","follow") == 0) { .echo found follow }
```

And combine it all together:

```
.foreach (entry {!dumpheap -type System.String -short})
{
   .foreach /pS 4 /ps 99 (reftoken {!refs ${entry} -target}) 
   { 
      .if ($sicmp("${reftoken}","follow") == 0) 
      { 
            .printf "${entry}\n"
      } 
   }
}
```

In one line:

```
 .foreach (entry {!dumpheap -type System.String -short}){.foreach /pS 4 /ps 99 (reftoken {!refs ${entry} -target}) {.if ($sicmp("${reftoken}","follow") == 0) {.printf "${entry}\n"}}}
```

Of course you can replace *.print* by any other command which is helpful in your situation.

I hope you can adapt this sample to use ReadLock.

Comment: This is a great answer. But I need a bit of clarification. What is `$sicmp`? Is it a pointer to a string comparison function from the CRT? Can you show how do you set its value?

Comment: `$iscmp()` is a MASM operator (function) which behaves like Win32 stricmp(). See `.hh MASM` for other functions. The first parameter `"${reftoken}"` is created by the `.foreach` command.