# Script Windbg to dump eax register after a call to FindFirstFileW

Tags: debugging, winapi, windbg

I'm trying to write a simple windbg script file to do the following:

1 - break on FindFirstFile

2 - execute the function to completion

3 - dump the dword contained in the eax register

I have tried the following, however it does not work as I expected.

```
bp FindFirstFileW
gu; r @eax; dd @eax

HANDLE WINAPI FindFirstFile(
  _In_  LPCTSTR           lpFileName,
  _Out_ LPWIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData
);
```

Is it possible to perform a pattern match on the lpFileName passed to FindFirstFile? If it matches, continue execution until the function completes. Then dump the dword returned to eax? If not continue normal execution.

Comment: Are these 2 questions? One about getting the value of @eax at the end of the method and the second about pattern matching `lpFileName`?

Comment: I see how the question is unclear. I would like yo extract the dword at eax based on a condition.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20069961/windbg-using-commands-for-the-condition-in-if/20082701#20082701 for pattern matching of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my the simple use case the following sequence of cmd works as desired.
set the initial bp using: `cdb -cf cmd.wds`

```
bp kernel32!FindNextFileA
```

upon reaching bp: `$<c:scripts\eax.wds`

```
t
gu
r @eax
dd @eax l1
```

Here is the output:

```
0:000> g
Breakpoint 5 hit
eax=0017fb44 ebx=00000000 ecx=004157a4 edx=0000005c esi=0017f934 edi=0017fc98
eip=74a8e27b esp=0017f928 ebp=0017fc98 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz ac pe cy
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000297
kernel32!FindFirstFileA:
74a8e27b ff25640aa874    jmp     dword ptr [kernel32!_imp__FindFirstFileA (74a80a64)] ds:002b:74a80a64={KERNELBASE!FindFirstFileA (7572aaa9)}
0:000> $<c:\scripts\eax.wds
0:000> t
eax=0017fb44 ebx=00000000 ecx=004157a4 edx=0000005c esi=0017f934 edi=0017fc98
eip=7572aaa9 esp=0017f928 ebp=0017fc98 iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz ac pe cy
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000297
KERNELBASE!FindFirstFileA:
7572aaa9 8bff            mov     edi,edi
0:000> gu
eax=004e8818 ebx=00000000 ecx=e310b772 edx=00000000 esi=0017f934 edi=0017fc98
eip=004118c9 esp=0017f934 ebp=0017fc98 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
>  107:                 searchHandle = FindFirstFile(searchPattern, &findData);
   108:                 if (searchHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
   109:                         ReportError(_T("Error opening Search Handle."), 0, TRUE);
   110:                         return FALSE;
   111:                 }
lsW!TraverseDirectory+0xb9:
004118c9 3bf4            cmp     esi,esp
0:000> r @eax
eax=004e8818
0:000> dd @eax l1
004e8818  00000034
```

Now I can see the HANDLE == 34. Which I can use procexp to verify.

Answer (score 2):

`FindFirstFileA / W` returns a `handle` not a file name.
what do you plan to do by dumping the return value ? it can only be used in subsequent `FindNextXXX`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
int wmain (int argc, wchar_t *argv[]) 
{
  if(argc!=2)
  {
    printf ("pl provide a wildcard for filename\n");
    return 0;
  }
  WIN32_FIND_DATAW fd = {0};
  HANDLE fifo = NULL;
  if(( fifo = FindFirstFileW(argv[1],&fd) ) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    printf("file not found\n");
    return 0;
  }    
  printf("unicode fulname %S\n",fd.cFileName);
  return 1;
}
```

assuming you compile the code above 
write a script file like this
set a bp on the api run to execute on break display registers and goup and redisplay registers dump eax and poi(eax) and print out the description of handle pointed by eax

```
bu kernel32!FindFirstFileW;
g
r
gu
r
r eax
dd @eax l1
!handle poi(@eax) ff
?? fd
```

and run windbg like this 
**windbg -c "$$>a< script.txt" fififi.exe *.cpp**

```
Processing initial command '$$>a< script.txt'
0:000> $$>a< script.txt
Breakpoint 0 hit
eax=0013fd24 ebx=7ffdb000 ecx=0013ff74 edx=00000000 esi=000344a8 edi=00aaf600
eip=7c80ef81 esp=0013fd14 ebp=0013ff78 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac po nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000212
kernel32!FindFirstFileW:
7c80ef81 8bff            mov     edi,edi
eax=00152c40 ebx=7ffdb000 ecx=000068af edx=7c97e140 esi=000344a8 edi=00aaf600
eip=00401058 esp=0013fd20 ebp=0013ff78 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
fififi!wmain+0x58:
00401058 83f8ff          cmp     eax,0FFFFFFFFh
eax=00152c40
00152c40  000007f4
Handle 7f4
  Type          File
  Attributes    0
  GrantedAccess 0x100001:
         Synch
         Read/List
  HandleCount   2
  PointerCount  3
  No Object Specific Information available
struct _WIN32_FIND_DATAW
   +0x000 dwFileAttributes : 0x2020
   +0x004 ftCreationTime   : _FILETIME Nov 24 09:07:34 2015
   +0x00c ftLastAccessTime : _FILETIME Nov 24 09:26:53 2015
   +0x014 ftLastWriteTime  : _FILETIME Nov 24 09:26:53 2015
   +0x01c nFileSizeHigh    : 0
   +0x020 nFileSizeLow     : 0x1aa
   +0x024 dwReserved0      : 0
   +0x028 dwReserved1      : 0
   +0x02c cFileName        : [260]  "fififi.cpp"
   +0x234 cAlternateFileName : [14]  ""
```

edit

- 1  the returned handle is opaque
- 2) only !handle info can be printed from the returned handle
- 3) in user mode ObjectNameInformation is generally not available
- 4) FindFirsFile is a one time initializing API and is generally not
  called again until FindClose is called so logically there cant exist
  a recurring condition
- 5) for pattern matching of file names you should set conditions on
  FindNext
- 6) last but not least ?? fd is usable only if you compile the code in
  reply  where fd is WIN32_FIND_DATAW  ?? is is c++ expression
  evaluator in windbg and prints out the type information if it existed
  on a local variable which fd tends to be in the code in above **(IT IS
  NOT A GENERIC  WINDBG COMMAND )**

Comment: I agree with you regarding the return. I want to see the handle returned.  This would help me validate an issue I having with a storage system returning bad values.

Comment: So the script is not working for me. It return the wrong handle and ?? fd fails. what is ?? fd ?

Comment: @d_blk, `fd` is the name of the variable defined in line 10 in blabb's code. You can look at `[ebp+c]` which holds the second parameter to `FindFirstFile` if you're debugging code for which you don't have private symbols.

Comment: I couldn't just leave it at that. You can use the following conditional breakpoint with blabb's code: `bu kernel32!FindFirstFileW "r @$t0 = poi(esp+8); gu; .if (@eax == -1) { .printf \"FindFirstFile returned INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE\\n\"; !gle; } .else { .printf \"Found file: %mu\\n\", @$t0+2c; }"`. If the file is found is will display it's name. Otherwise it will use the `!gle` extension to display the last error.